# Grails 2.x class from src/java not resolving in plugin

Tags: grails

As it is known that the  `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder` class has been deprecated in grails 2.3.x onwards. But there are many plugin that use it.
In one of my application I happen to use https://grails.org/plugin/excel-import?skipRedirect=true which is deprecated and no equivalent exists for grails 2.4 (though there is one for grails 3). 
My application uses this plugin and I would prefer not having to refractor it to use the latest version. So is there a way so that the `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder` resolves to  `Holders.grailsApplication` ?

I have already created a `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder` in src/java folder which has this content:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2004-2005 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons;

import grails.util.GrailsUtil;
import grails.util.Holders;

/**
 * Static singleton holder for the GrailsApplication instance.
 *
 * @author Marc Palmer (marc@anyware.co.uk)
 *
 * @deprecated Use dependency injection or implement GrailsApplicationAware instead
 */
@Deprecated
public abstract class ApplicationHolder {

    /**
     * @return The GrailsApplication instance
     * @deprecated Use dependency injection instead
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static GrailsApplication getApplication() {
        GrailsUtil.deprecated("Method ApplicationHolder.getApplication() is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Grails.");
        return Holders.getGrailsApplication();
    }

    /**
     * @param application The application to set
     * @deprecated Use dependency injection instead
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static void setApplication(GrailsApplication application) {
        Holders.setGrailsApplication(application);
    }
}
```

But still when I run the project I get this error:

```
..myapproot\target\work\plugins\excel-import-1.0.0\grails-app\services\org\grails\plugins\excelimport\ExcelImportService.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
 @ line 13, column 1.
   import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
   ^

1 error
```

So not sure how do I make the excel-import plugin use this class(as its not able to find ApplicationHolder class from grails 2.4.4 which my application uses)?

**EDIT**
I even tried running with grails command line instead of intellij. Same result!

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way so that the
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder resolves to
>   Holders.grailsApplication ?

If you really need to use the older version of the plugin, one hackus-majoris would be to add your own `ApplicationHolder` class under `src/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationHolder.groovy` (or `.java`).

Comment: I created `APP-FOLDER/src/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationHolder.groovy` in my app but it still threw the same error.

Comment: @UdayReddy I can't recreate that.  Without an example project it may be difficult to troubleshoot.  I am sorry I can't help.  Best of luck!

Comment: Note that in order for the plugin to reference the class, the class will have to be in the plugin's project.  I can't tell if that is the issue you are having or not.

Comment: So do you suggest having the plugin inside the code base and create `ApplicationHolder.groovy`?

Comment: No.  I suggest looking into it to see if there is a newer version of the plugin which doesn't reference the holder and if not, open an issue request to improve that in the plugin.  It will be a trivial change.